# ImageMagick Error: "corrupted size vs. prev_size" in libc.so on Linux

Tags: imagemagick, glibc, libc

I am using `imagemagick 7` to read and write some `TIFF` files. I have `C++` code to do the same and it is working fine with windows. I am facing this issue while writing TIFF file on Linux. I magemagick is giving crash while creating ImageMagick Image and writing Image to file.

I have collected the traces of crash but it seems difficult to analyse with traces.

I am getting below error message:

```
*** Error in `TestReadWriteImage': corrupted size vs. prev_size: 0x0000000001ef0430 ***
<br/>
======= Backtrace: ========= <br/>
/lib64/libc.so.6(+0x7f5d4)[0x7f81724b75d4]<br/>
/lib64/libc.so.6(+0x82de4)[0x7f81724bade4]<br/>
/lib64/libc.so.6(+0x8382c)[0x7f81724bb82c]<br/>
/lib64/libc.so.6(realloc+0x1d2)[0x7f81724bd832]<br/>
/lib64/libtiff.so.5(+0xd863)[0x7f816543e863]<br/>
/lib64/libtiff.so.5(TIFFSetField+0x94)[0x7f816543f124]<br/>
/home/data/linux_a64/code/bin/tiff.so(+0x7457)[0x7f81656ac457]<br/>
/home/data/linux_a64/code/bin/libMagickCore-7.Q8HDRI.so.0(WriteImage+0x260)[0x7f8168fc9490]<br/>
/home/data/linux_a64/code/bin/libMagick++-7.Q8HDRI.so.0(_ZN6Magick5Image5writeERKSs+0x43)[0x7f8168d1d853]<br/>


**Sample C++ Code:**<br/>
 *uchar* *pixels; // This variable contains some pixel data* <br/>
  *Magick::Image* *imImage = new Magick::Image(3, 3, "RGB",Magick::CharPixel, pixels);* <br/>
  *imImage->write("/home/tmp/Output.tiff");*
```

I am getting crash for last 2 instructions.

I am not sure where to look for problem.

Is it ImageMagick, libc or libtiff behind crash ?

If some one has faced same issue please help me out .

Answer (score 0):

> I am not sure where to look for problem.

You have heap corruption (most likely caused by earlier overflow of a heap allocated buffer).

*The* standard tool for finding such problems is [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org).

> I have collected the traces of crash but it seems difficult to analyse with traces.

The problem with debugging heap corruption (without specialized tools) is that the place where the problem manifests often has very little to do with the place where the problem actually happens.